# When I include "cocos-ext.h",other cocos file will report error

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I include "cocos-ext.h",other cocos file will report error ,such like function createScene() of Layer  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2jIC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cocos. But it seems that cocos-ext.h contains different definition of `Scene` so the function `HelloWorld::CreateScene` has conflict signature with its declaration.

You should put `#include "cocos-ext.h"` into your header file instead of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks,I have resolved this question.The reason is that after cocos Version3.4, the way to include ".h file " has changed.